# Local Serverless Invoke of Void Handler - InvokeBridge Exception

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless

After running "mvn package" to generate a valid, updated .jar file, I get an error when trying to invoke any of my functions locally:

```
> serverless invoke local --function getExternalXMLData

Serverless: In order to get human-readable output, please implement "toString()" method of your "ApiGatewayResponse" object.

java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.serverless.InvokeBridge cannot access a member of class java.lang.Void with modifiers "private"
at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
at com.serverless.InvokeBridge.invoke(InvokeBridge.java:68)
at com.serverless.InvokeBridge.<init>(InvokeBridge.java:36)
at com.serverless.InvokeBridge.main(InvokeBridge.java:133)
```

These are all working functions that are deployed to Production. Here's a short bare-bones example of a Handler that receives that error. It does some background processing and both the input and output are Void:

```
public class ExternalXMLHandler implements RequestHandler<Void, Void> {

    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(final Void input, final Context context) {
        System.out.println("handleRequestExecuted");
        return null;
    }

}
```

I can invoke the live versions, but I can't perform a local invoke. I can get by the error by getting rid of the Voids in the RequestHandler, but that's not how these functions work. What's going on here, and how can I get local invoke working?

Comment: It doesn't like "RequestHandler<Void, Void>", though I can't figure out why. This was working for me the last time I opened this project a month ago.

Comment: It doesn't like "RequestHandler<Void, Void>", though I can't figure out why. This was working for me when I was last working on it a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is existing one and looked by developers. Follow the below link:

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4415